# Arrays Loop Logic

Tags: java, arrays, jtable, logic

This is probably going to be a simple one.  I just can't see what's wrong with my logic for my loop statements in its current form.  I appreciate anyone willing to tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I'm setting the values of specific cells in a JTable so that when a radio button is selected it will calculate a new pay amount for an entire column.  The issues I'm running into are:

- I only want it to peform the calculations once.  If you hit the one percent raise button after already selecting it, I don't want to keep adding an additional 1 percent raise each time, which it is currently doing.
- When you change from a 1 percent raise to a 5 percent raise or 2 percent raise I want it to calculate the 5 percent raise off the base pay and display that, not add the 5 percent raise to their already raised pay, which it is currently doing.
- When you press the reset radio button it should return the pay amount to the default amount that was previously in the table. Currently it does nothing.

  ```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {                 
      double[] savedPay = new double[outputTable.getRowCount()];
      double raisePayAMT = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < outputTable.getRowCount(); i++)
      {
          savedPay[i] = (Double) outputTable.getValueAt(i,3);
      }
      if(oneRadio.isSelected())
      {

          for(int i = 0; i < outputTable.getRowCount(); i++)
          {
              raisePayAMT = savedPay[i] + (savedPay[i]*.02);
              outputTable.setValueAt(raisePayAMT,i,3);
              outputTable.repaint();
          }
      }
      else if(twoRadio.isSelected())
      {

          for(int i = 0; i < outputTable.getRowCount(); i++)
          {
              raisePayAMT = savedPay[i] + (savedPay[i]*.02);
              outputTable.setValueAt(raisePayAMT,i,3);
              outputTable.repaint();
          }
      }
      else if(fiveRadio.isSelected())
      {

          for(int i = 0; i < outputTable.getRowCount(); i++)
          {
              raisePayAMT = savedPay[i] + (savedPay[i]*.05);
              outputTable.setValueAt(raisePayAMT,i,3);
              outputTable.repaint();
          }                
      }
      else if(resetRadio.isSelected())
      {

          for(int i = 0; i < outputTable.getRowCount(); i++)
          {                    
              outputTable.setValueAt(savedPay[i],i,3);
              outputTable.repaint();
          }    
      }
  ```

  }

Comment: So if I'm reading this correctly every time you hit a different radio button the value is being incremented?  If that is in fact the problem, it's because you are storing the newly raised values in the table.  So the new default is the raised amount each time.  You need a default set of values saved somewhere if you want to revert back, or you can check for the previously selected button and do a reduction on the amount but that can get nasty kind of quick.

Comment: I think you're on to something.  Since I was creating my array of savedPay in the radioListener class every time a radio button was clicked it was storing the new values into savedPay.  I think I should be able to create that array somewhere else to prevent that.  see, I knew at it's heart it would be simple, just had been staring at it for about an hour not making progress.

Comment: I know the feeling.  Best of luck in getting it solved.  If you run into any more road blocks on it feel free to update and I will help best I can.